# Require column data side by side with respect to column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data like below where PLO and status field for one WPID.

```
PR       PN       WPID   WPN           PLO  Status
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   a1  PP
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   b1  RTS
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   c1  Hold
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   d1  Completed
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   e1  Review
1233    12331   5377820 12331-def-1-c   b1  RTS
```

How can I get the result like below where each PLO and status is side by side.
Is there any  way to do this?

```
PR       PN     WPID    WPN             PLO1 Status1 PLO2 Status2 PLO3 Status3
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   a1   PP      b1  RTS      d1     Completed
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   c1   Hold                           
1233    12331   5377820 12331-abc-1-c   e1   Review
1233    12331   5377820 12331-def-1-c                b1  RTS
```

Comment: Is 5 the maximum number of rows that will be combined into a single row?

Comment: Could you explain more detail about how could you create your `PLO1`...`PLO2`    columns?

Comment: Hi Grodon, this is just sample, I have huge data that has to represented in this way.... I do not want in single row, I want result set as shown in my question

Comment: Hi Shih, I just wanted to three PLO and status in different columns, i created respective PLO1,PLO2,PLO3 and Status1,Status2,Status3

Comment: any logic as to which goes into which column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it this seems to require a slightly altered pivot query, and can be achieved without joining the table to itself by following a pattern like:

```
SELECT
   pr, pn, wpid, wpn,
   --all PLO that should appear in same column go in each IN
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('a1','c1','e1') THEN plo END) as plo1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('a1','c1','e1') THEN status END) as status1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('b1') THEN plo END) as plo2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('b1') THEN status END) as status2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('d1') THEN plo END) as plo3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN plo IN ('d1') THEN status END as status3
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  pr, pn, wpid, wpn,
  CASE --all PLO that should appear on same row go in same IN, if adding another WHEN increment the number at line end too
    WHEN plo IN ('a1','b1','d1') THEN 1
    WHEN plo IN ('c1') THEN 2
    WHEN plo IN ('e1') THEN 3
  END
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nK39QrjcxpZgkRokStXQhB/0

To extend this add more MAX CASE WHEN to the select list (to add more columns) and more WHEN clauses to the case in the GROUP BY (to create more rows), in accordance to the rule written in the comments

Comment: Hi Caius, PLO name can be in any manner as its a huge table...and so many PLO are avaibale

Comment: Better get typing then. You'll only have to type as many variations as there are different values of PLO

Answer (score 0):

Select 
pr
plo,
case  when 
plo='a1' THEN 'a1' end as PLO1

from NewTable t1